# Python : Was expecting one of: <NEWLINE>

Tags: python, api

I wrote

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

    def ANdata(key, id, format, nR, start) :
        queryUrl = 'http://developer.website.com/api/v4/type/news?api_key=' + key + '&id=' + id + '&format=' + format + '&results=' + nR + '&start=' + start
        print "test"
```

The error was :

```
   Encountered "\"test\"" at line 6, column 11. Was expecting one of:     <NEWLINE> ...     "(" ...     "[" ...     ";" ...     "," ...     "." ...     "+" ...     "-" ...     "*" ...     "/" ...     "//" ...     "<<" ...     
 ">>" ...     "%" ...     "^" ...     "|" ...     "&" ...     "=" ...     ">" ...     "<" ...     "==" ...     "<=" ...     ">=" ...     "!=" ...     "+=" ...     "-=" ...     "*=" ...     "/=" ...     "//=" ...     "%=" ...     "&=" ...     
 "|=" ...     "^=" ...     "<<=" ...     ">>=" ...     "**=" ...     "or" ...     "and" ...     "not" ...     "is" ...     "in" ...     "if" ...     ";" ...     "," ...
```

Do you see a problem ?

Comment: I am using Pydev, the src folder is : /usr/bin/python3.2mu

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these Python scripts giving syntax errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059429/why-are-these-python-scripts-giving-syntax-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the problem with the 2.3mu . 
But I fixed this after changing to 2.7.

Answer (score 9):

In Python 3, `print` was changed from a keyword to a function. So to use it, you have to put its argument in parentheses:

```
print("test")
```

In Python 2.x, it will work with or without the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of error, in my experience, quite often (still) crops up in PyDev in Eclipse when you copy code (e.g. from a book).

It is inevitable that it will crop up, and can't be "put right", when it is caused by spurious, and invisible, Unicode characters, such as "Zero-width space" or "Control".

You might think that copying text from a book to a simple text editor app of some kind might automatically "clean up" the text, for onward copy-pasting, but often it doesn't, in my humble (and bitter) experience.

The best way to check whether this error is caused by this sort of thing is to inspect the line of text in a Unicode character inspector. At the time of writing I recommend [this](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%E2%80%8BTask.__new__.__defaults__%20%3D%20%28None%2C%20None%2C%20False%2C%20None%29).

After that, cleaning up this code is not something you'd want to do by hand.

You should be able to do this using Eclipse's own "Find/Replace" dialog (Ctrl-F):

- check "Regular expressions"
- put this in Find: "\u200B" (e.g. in case of Zero-width space)

Alternatively you could use Notepad++:

- copy the contaminated text in question to a new Notepad++ doc
- search and replace with "Regular expression" selected
- Notepad++ needs you to do this to stipulate a Unicode character: "\x{200B}" (e.g. in the case of Zero-width space)
- select-all, copy and paste back to Eclipse